# bitsadmin.exe / How to download file through http proxy

Tags: windows, command-line, proxy

This is good enough to download file:

```
bitsadmin.exe /transfer "JobName" https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png C:\test.png
```

However, How about if wanna download file through http proxy? or socks5

Answer (score 2):

See the **/Util /SetIEProxy** flags - to quote https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa362813(v=vs.85).aspx:

> The following examples show how to use the /Util /SetIEProxy switch:
>
> bitsadmin /util /setieproxy localsystem AUTODETECT
>
> bitsadmin /util /setieproxy localsystem MANUAL_PROXY proxy1,proxy2,proxy3 NULL
>
> bitsadmin /util /setieproxy localsystem MANUAL_PROXY proxy1:80 ""

Also note, that BITS should use the users internet explorer proxy settings by default - although that will not apply to system accounts, so the above is needed if it's being run as a scheduled task as local system / network service for example.

I believe a complete set of steps that would transfer a file and set proxy settings for a specific job would be as follows:

```
bitsadmin /create /download MyJob
bitsadmin.exe /addFile MyJob https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png C:\temp\test.png
bitsadmin /setproxysettings MyJob OVERRIDE proxy1:80 "<local>"
bitsadmin /resume MyJob

bitsadmin /monitor

bitsadmin /complete MyJob
```

Comment: Ohh, I did not get... can u please show me how full command looks like (My command at top plus bitsadmin /util /setieproxy localsystem MANUAL_PROXY 1.1.1.1:5555 and I will be grateful for u.

Comment: let my edit my answer a second with what i think is a complete set of steps - i've not got a proxy here now which makes it harder ;)

Comment: You should run the first 5 commands and once you see that the download is complete, run the last command to finish the job and then you will see the file.

Comment: Also, if you have to authenticate your proxy you can add the following after the /setproxysettings command.
bitsadmin /setcredentials MyJob PROXY BASIC <user> <pass>